# AWS Lambda function times out when reading bucket file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Last two lines of code below are the issue. I have line of sight to the csv file in the bucket as can be seen in the printout  below, the file in the bucket is an object that is returned with key/value conventions.  The problem is the .read(). It ALWAYS times out. Per the pointers when I first posted this question I've changed my settings in AWS to 3 minutes before a function times out and I also try to download it but that returns None.  I guess the central questions are why does the .read() function take so long and what is missing in my download_file command? The file is small: 1KB. Any help appreciated thanks

```py
import boto3
import csv

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('polly-partner')
obj = bucket.Object(key='CyclingLog.csv')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = obj.get()
    print(response)
    key = obj.key
    filepath = '/tmp/' + key
    print(bucket.download_file(key, filepath))
    lines = response['Body'].read()
    print(lines)
```

Printout is:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed"
}

Request ID:
"541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539 Version: $LATEST
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '0860AE16F7A96522', 'HostId': 'D6k1kFcCv9Qz70ANXjEnPQEFsKpAntqJND9FRf5diae3WWmDbVDJENkPCd1oOOOfFt8BJ8b8OOY=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'D6k1kFcCv9Qz70ANXjEnPQEFsKpAntqJND9FRf5diae3WWmDbVDJENkPCd1oOOOfFt8BJ8b8OOY=', 'x-amz-request-id': '0860AE16F7A96522', 'date': 'Wed, 01 Apr 2020 17:51:49 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Thu, 19 Mar 2020 17:17:37 GMT', 'etag': '"b56479c4073a90943b3d862d5d4ff38d-6"', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'text/csv', 'content-length': '50000056', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 1}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 19, 17, 17, 37, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 50000056, 'ETag': '"b56479c4073a90943b3d862d5d4ff38d-6"', 'ContentType': 'text/csv', 'Metadata': {}, 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f536df1ddc0>}
None
END RequestId: 541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539
REPORT RequestId: 541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539  Duration: 12923.11 ms   Billed Duration: 13000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 129 MB Init Duration: 362.26 ms    
RequestId: 541f6cc6-2195-409a-88d3-e98c57fbd539 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: How big is the file? If it is a big file, have you tried it with a smaller file?

Comment: File size is important. What size is the file? You're using 128MB out of 128MB.

Comment: Yes! That would explain things. The `read()` command is attempting to load the file into memory. If that exceeds limits, it would end the Lambda function early. One option is to **download** the file rather than streaming it into memory. Then, operate on the local file through normal Python commands.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says: `Task timed out after 3.00 seconds`

You can increase the Timeout on a Lambda function by opening the function in the console, going to the **Basic settings** section and clicking **Edit**.

While you say that you increased this timeout setting, the fact that it is timing-out after *exactly* 3 seconds suggests that the setting has not been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The timeout setting very explicitly states 2 min 3 seconds. There's something about the .read() function that makes the execution quite different and I've been searching for answer for some time to no avail.

Comment: A timeout after exactly 3 second suggests that the function timeout is set to that value. It would not be likely to timeout at that exact moment in repeated executions of the function. Here's an experiment... insert a `time.sleep(5)` statement and a `print('slept')` before the `read()` to see whether the function times-out, or if it continues to the `read()` statement. (You'll need to `import time` too.)

Comment: 'slept' prints out per your recommendation. Still Runtime.ExitError with Billed Duration: 13900 ms. In settings timeout remains 2 min 3 secs

Comment: Excellent! It's good to see that the duration is no longer 3 seconds. Could you please add the output you received to your question? The question does not currently mention an `ExitError`, so I'd be interested to see exactly what it says.

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: c3630348-04b4-4355-953b-b543c2e1eea2 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed"
}

Request ID:
"c3630348-04b4-4355-953b-b543c2e1eea2"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: c3630348-04b4-4355-953b-b543c2e1eea2 Version: $LATEST
slept
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '514A15FA578FC7D7', 'HostId': '/OIIIw7HAZnaEBEAJlibKlyE5kYuExs+RLQewQERDN53c/oAETV/zCSyWGSZBUmf22Billed Duration: 10900 ms Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed
Runtime.ExitError

Comment: Pardon the sloppiness of last post the original error message was too long for comment format so I chopped out what looked like unnecessary text in the middle. Lmk what else you might need I appreciate this cheers

Comment: Could you please put the output in your Question, rather than a comment?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, (and hopefully solved long ago!), but I ended up here so I'll share my findings.

These generic Runtime error messages:

```
"Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed Runtime.ExitError"
```

...when accompanied by something like this on the REPORT line:

```
Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 129 MB Init Duration: 362.26 ms
```

...Looks like a low memory issue. Especially when  "Max Memory Used" is >= "Memory Size"

From what I've seen, Lambda can and often will utilize up to 100% memory without issue ([Discussed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432922/aws-lambda-reaching-memory-size-with-no-error)). But when you attempt to load data into memory, or perform memory intensive processing (copying large data sets stored in variables?), the Python runtime can hit a memory error and exit.
Unfortunately, it isn't very well documented, or logged, or captured with CloudWatch metrics.

I believe the same error in NodeJS runtime looks like:

```
"Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted (core dumped)"
```