# AWS Lambda reaching Memory Size with no error

Tags: aws-lambda

I have started seeing `Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB` messages in my CloudWatch logs.  I would expect that when the limit is reached the lambda should exit with an error.  However, this is not happening.  Aside from the above message, there is no indication that the lambda failed.

Does anybody know more about what is happening under the covers in these cases?  Is the lambda still running and maybe AWS is doing some magic to manage the memory so it doesn't fail, but maybe the lambda just takes longer to run?

Or is it failing without any log or notification?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't know for sure how Lambda manages memory - if nodejs is anything like c# in memory management, maybe Lambda can force garbage collections when the instance is approaching max memory. However I did a quick test by allocating a ton of memory which was not GC-able in a nodejs Lambda, and the Lambda exited with `Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed`. Based on that I don't believe your Lambda used more memory than allocated.

Comment: Thanks @404, that's helpful.  I have seen some posts and examples online that do result in the error that you mentioned.  I kind of wish that I was seeing those errors since it would eliminate the ambiguity.  I agree with you in that I don't believe that my lambda is exceeding its memory and therefore failing.  But I am hoping to get a little more understanding so that I can be more confident in that belief.

Comment: Maybe put some logging in the handler right before it returns, so if it prints and there's no exception you know the Lambda executed fully and successfully.